# A context consumer was rendered with multiple children, or a child that isn't a function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

The complete error says:

*A context consumer was rendered with multiple children, or a child that isn't a function. A context consumer expects a single child that is a function. If you did pass a function, make sure there is no trailing or leading whitespace around it.*

I have read several solutions here and but none of them have worked for me. This is my code:

**TransactionsContext.jsx**

```
export const TransactionContext = React.createContext();

export const TransactionProvider = ({ children }) => {
    return (
        <TransactionContext.Provider value='test'>
            { children }
        </TransactionContext.Provider>
    );
}
```

**main.jsx**

```
import { TransactionContext } from './context/TransactionsContext';

ReactDOM.render(
  <TransactionContext>
    <App />
  </TransactionContext>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

**App.jsx**

```
const App = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="min-h-screen">
      <div>
        <Navbar />
        <Welcome />
      </div>
      <Services />
      <Transactions />
      <Footer />
    </div>
  )
}
```

**Welcome.jsx**

```
const Welcome = () => {

const { value } = useContext(TransactionContext);
console.log(value);
...
}
```

[image]

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Send an object instead of a string On TransactionsContext.jsx

```
<TransactionContext.Provider value={{value: 'test'}}>
```

Once the context is created, it starts [with the context provider](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#contextprovider).

Replace the Context for the Provider main.jsx

```
import { TransactionProvider } from './context/TransactionsContext';

ReactDOM.render(
  <TransactionProvider>
    <App />
  </TransactionProvider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Then use the context on Welcome.jsx

```
const Welcome = () => {
    const { value } = useContext(TransactionContext);
    console.log(value);
    // or
    // const tc = useContext(TransactionContext);
    // console.log(tc.value);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `main.jsx` you should wrap the `App` component in `TransactionProvider`, not `TransactionContext`:

```
import { TransactionProvider } from './context/TransactionsContext';

ReactDOM.render(
  <TransactionProvider>
    <App />
  </TransactionProvider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```